# ¿Cómo seleccionar todo y copiar texto de todos los controles?

Tags: c#, wpf

En una ventana de wpf tengo 6 DataGrid y 6 Label. ¿Es posible agregar un menú de click derecho a la ventana y seleccionar el texto de todos los controles y después copiar este texto?

Answer (score 2):

Si no me equivoco aquí tienes un preciso tutorial de cómo hacer eso:
https://freelanceprogramer.wordpress.com/2013/11/10/seleccionar-automaticamente-todo-el-texto-en-foco-en-el-control-textbox-de-wpf/. Explica lo que quieres hacer, te pone los scripts que deberás utilizar.

Según explica el tutorial, debemos crear una variable estática:

```
static bool conFoco_txtBuscar; (esta variable establece si el texto se encuentra “con foco” = “true” ó “false”)

EVENTO GodFocus:

gotfocus  

EVENTO GotMouseFocus:

gotmousefocus

EVENTO LostFocus

lostfocus
```

Acá les dejo el mismo código en formato de texto ya que el código de arriba son imágenes y no se puede copiar el texto en el portapapeles:

```
/*variable estatica*/

static bool conFoco_txtBuscar;

/*eventos*/

private void txtBuscarCliente_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
          if (Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Released)
          {
                    txtBuscarCliente.SelectAll();
                    conFoco_txtBuscar = true;
          }
}

private void txtBuscarCliente_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
          if (!conFoco_txtBuscar && txtBuscarCliente.SelectionLength == 0)
          {
                    conFoco_txtBuscar = true;
                    txtBuscarCliente.SelectAll();
          }
}

private void txtBuscarCliente_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
          conFoco_txtBuscar = false;
          txtBuscarCliente.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Y he analizado el código y talvez no me explique bien en mi pregunta, era si hay alguna forma de que al dar click derecho en la ventana aparezca el menú con un ítem para copiar todo el texto al mismo tiempo el contenido de todos los  6 DataGrid y los 6 label. De esta forma el usuario solo copiaría y pegaría una sola vez hacia excel. Lo he podido hacer pero seleccionando texto y copiando en cada DataGrid por separado.